# How to copy(backup) Azure CosmosDB container to Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

There are many Containers in my CosmosDB Database, And I need to backup some, but not all containers everyday. Some container are backed up for 7days, some are 15 days.

1. I don't want to use incremental backup, because we do backup once everyday.
2. Maybe we store backup data-set into Azure blob storage.

**The thing I don't know** => `container == collection`. Azure document is so confusing!

Comment: sorry not clear waht youre asking ? you d like to backup your cosmos container ? the out of the box way not working for you ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore

Comment: @Thomas I have edited the description. I want to backup specific containers, not all containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can create a job on Azure Data Factory (aka ADF, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db), use the ADF job to copy data from these containers, and save the data as files (one file for one container) in somewhere (like Azure Blob Storage).

Comment: Can ADF job copy data backup a specific container but all containers？

Comment: Specific. You could even setup a query for additional filtering.